# Spark on Kubernetes: Executor-Driver Communication Issue with OpenShift Cluster and Macbook

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

Can someone spread some insights on below issue?

I am running a Spark job where the driver is hosted on my MacBook (notebook/pyspark) and the executors are supposed to run on an OpenShift cluster. While I can successfully create a Spark session from my MacBook, the job execution fails, causing a recurring loop as evidenced by the logs shown below. I have attached an image to simulate the scenario.

I think there is a problem with job status communication circling back to spark driver. Not sure if I have to check firewall settings on MacBook to ensure no blocking of incoming connections on driver host and port.

Same code works well within the openshift cluster.

Setup:

Spark Driver: Running through jupyter notebook pyspark on my macbook, through VPN
Spark Executors: Intended to run on OpenShift Kubernetes cluster
Connection: I intend to establish a communication channel between the driver and executors over the network.

[image]

```
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print(host_ip)

# Set the configuration for the SparkSession
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("Event Driven Spark - Clientside Request") \
    .setMaster("k8s://https://api.myk8s.org:6443") \
...
    .set("spark.executor.instances", "1") \
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "512m") \
    .set("spark.driver.host", host_ip) \
    .set("spark.driver.port", "29413") \
    .set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0") \
    .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "client") \
    .set("spark.kubernetes.driver.scheduler.name", "event-driven-pyspark-deenu-macbook") \
    .set("spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile", "podtemplate.yaml") \
    .set("spark.kubernetes.trust.certificates", "true") \
    .set("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.oauthToken", OC_TOKEN)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")

print('\n\tSpark Version: ', sc.version)
print('\tSpark Application ID: ', sc.applicationId, '\n')

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4., 8., 5.],
    'c': ['GFG1', 'GFG2', 'GFG3'],
    'd': [date(2000, 8, 1), date(2000, 6, 2),
          date(2000, 5, 3)],
    'e': [datetime(2000, 8, 1, 12, 0),
          datetime(2000, 6, 2, 12, 0),
          datetime(2000, 5, 3, 12, 0)]
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

# df.printSchema()
df.show()
# print(pd.version__)
spark.stop()
```

Output:

```
    23/08/09 22:13:14 WARN Utils: Your hostname, HC67Q6PLQX resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.0.0.35 instead (on interface en0)
23/08/09 22:13:14 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
23/08/09 22:13:14 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

        Spark Version:  3.4.1
        Spark Application ID:  spark-0bf7f463722642c2ad5c49a58bb44ea3 

23/08/09 22:13:46 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
23/08/09 22:13:46 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/Users/e1443372/Documents/Workspace/Projects/OpenShift/workspace/Bitnami-spark/daut-spark-image-3.4.1/spark-driver-nb-container-3.4.1/examples/Deenu/spark-warehouse'.
23/08/09 22:13:47 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 106.514 ms
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1 output partitions
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[6] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 15.0 KiB, free 127.2 MiB)
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 7.6 KiB, free 127.2 MiB)
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:49486 (size: 7.6 KiB, free: 127.2 MiB)
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1535
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[6] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
23/08/09 22:13:48 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
23/08/09 22:13:50 INFO ExecutorPodsAllocator: Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 1, known: 0, sharedSlotFromPendingPods: 2147483647.
23/08/09 22:13:50 INFO BasicExecutorFeatureStep: Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
23/08/09 22:13:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 5 from BlockManagerMaster.
23/08/09 22:13:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 5 requested
23/08/09 22:13:50 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 5
```

Comment: "Client Mode
Starting with Spark 2.4.0, it is possible to run Spark applications on Kubernetes in client mode. When your application runs in client mode, the driver can run inside a pod or on a physical host. When running an application in client mode, it is recommended to account for the following factors:

Here is the reference from documentation. I wonder how do I achieve this in my scenario. Client Mode Networking
Spark executors must be able to connect to the Spark driver over a hostname and a port that is routable from the Spark executors.